# res.render showing html code than rendering the page

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am new to ejs and I am trying to render a page using it. Here is the code

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get ("/user",(req,res) =>{
  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');    
  var id_token_decode=jwt_decoder(req.session.tokenSet.id_token);
  var decoded = jwt_decoder(req.session.tokenSet.access_token); 
  console.log(id_token_decode)
  console.log(decoded);
  console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/views/citizenHome.html'))
  res.render('citizenHome.ejs')
  
})
```

It is showing the html code rather than actually rendering the page. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');`   this line from the route

```
app.get ("/user",(req,res) =>{
  // res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');    <-- remove this line
  var id_token_decode=jwt_decoder(req.session.tokenSet.id_token);
  var decoded = jwt_decoder(req.session.tokenSet.access_token); 
  console.log(id_token_decode)
  console.log(decoded);
  console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/views/citizenHome.html'))
  res.render('citizenHome.ejs')
  
})
```

And also, what does `/views/citizenHome.html` this file do?

Comment: thanks it worked!!